# Stored Procedure Updating more than one time MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, mariadb

I have a stored procedure to update some rows in MySQL. But when I call the stored procedure, it affects more than actual rows.

Here is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `SP_INSERT_DATA`(
    IN `incoming_data` TEXT,
    IN `value_array` TEXT,
    IN `serial_number` VARCHAR(50),
    IN `data_timestamp` VARCHAR(50),
    OUT `result_id` INT,
    OUT `result_message` VARCHAR(500)
)
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN

DECLARE i INT;
DECLARE value_iteration VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE lcl_data_type_id INT;
DECLARE arr_data_type_name VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE affected_data_row_count INT;
DECLARE cstmr_id INT;


DECLARE exit handler FOR 40001
BEGIN
    GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1
    @p1 = MYSQL_ERRNO, @p2 = MESSAGE_TEXT;
    SET result_id = -2;
    SET result_message = CONCAT('RETURNED ERROR NO : ', @p1 , '\r\nMESSAGE TEXT : ',@p2);
ROLLBACK;
END;

DECLARE exit handler for sqlexception
BEGIN
    GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1
    @p1 = MYSQL_ERRNO, @p2 = MESSAGE_TEXT;
    SET result_id = -999;
    SET result_message = CONCAT('RETURNED ERROR NO : ', @p1 , '\r\nMESSAGE TEXT : ',@p2);
ROLLBACK;
END;

    START TRANSACTION;
    SET i = 1;
    SET affected_data_row_count = 0;
    SET cstmr_id = 0;
    SET result_id = 0;
    SET result_message = 'Success';
    
    SELECT id INTO cstmr_id FROM templaricustomers WHERE templaricustomers.customer_serial_number = serial_number LIMIT 1;
    IF(cstmr_id <> 0) THEN
        
        WHILE (LOCATE(',', value_array) > 0)
        DO
    
            SET arr_data_type_name = SUBSTRING_INDEX(value_array,',',i);
            SET value_array = SUBSTRING(value_array, LOCATE(',',value_array) + 1);
    
            SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(incoming_data, arr_data_type_name) INTO value_iteration;
            
            SET arr_data_type_name := SUBSTRING_INDEX(arr_data_type_name, ".", -1);
            
                IF (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM datatypes WHERE datatypes.data_name = arr_data_type_name) > 0 THEN 
                    SELECT id INTO lcl_data_type_id FROM datatypes WHERE datatypes.data_name = arr_data_type_name LIMIT 1;
                ELSE
                    INSERT INTO datatypes (datatypes.data_name,datatypes.description ,datatypes.inserted_date) VALUES(arr_data_type_name,arr_data_type_name,NOW());
                    SELECT id INTO lcl_data_type_id FROM datatypes WHERE datatypes.data_name = arr_data_type_name LIMIT 1;
                END IF;
                
                
                IF (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM mqttpacket WHERE mqttpacket.data_type_id = lcl_data_type_id AND mqttpacket.customer_id = cstmr_id) > 0 THEN
                    UPDATE mqttpacket SET mqttpacket.data_value = value_iteration , mqttpacket.inserted_time = data_timestamp WHERE mqttpacket.data_type_id = lcl_data_type_id AND mqttpacket.customer_id = cstmr_id;
                ELSE
                INSERT INTO mqttpacket (mqttpacket.data_type_id,mqttpacket.customer_id,mqttpacket.data_value,mqttpacket.inserted_time) VALUES(lcl_data_type_id,cstmr_id,value_iteration,data_timestamp);
                END IF;
                
                SET affected_data_row_count = affected_data_row_count +1;
                
        END WHILE;
        SET result_id = 0;
        SET result_message = CONCAT('Query performed successfully. Effected rows :  ',CAST(affected_data_row_count AS CHAR));

    ELSE
        SET result_id = -1;
        SET result_message = 'Customer Serial Number not found.';
    END IF;
        

COMMIT;
END
```

Here is how I call it:

```
CALL `SP_INSERT_DATA`('{"subcooling":-40,"B1":113,"B2":206,"B3":471,"B4":226,"B5":8,"B6":380,"B7":210,"B8":187,"Discharge":135,"Suction":120,"High_Pressure":90,"Low_Pressure":90,"Evaporation":73,"Condensation":73,"MAX_CMP_SPEED":1100,"Thermal_Limit":748,"SH":46,"EEV_pct":0,"COP":0,"DSH":60,"WaterFlux":8,"FanPower":1,"DeltaTtoStart":0,"DeltaPtoStart":60,"CMP_ROTOR_RPS":0,"SET_CH_FLASH":120,"SET_HP_FLASH":350,"SET_DHW_FLASH":470,"Defrosting":0,"B8_AVERAGE":63,"SET_PLANT":0,"SET_CH_BMS":160,"SET_HP_BMS":200,"SET_DHW_BMS":480,"SET_ACTIVE":200,"SET_DSH":250,"EEV_INJ_pct":0,"LPT":0,"HPT":0,"PLANT_MODE_MANUAL":0,"DHW_MODE_MANUAL":0,"WATER_FLOW":8,"DISCHARGE_TMP":135,"INVERTER_TMP":8,"ENVELOP_ZONE":1,"EEV_A_STEPS":0,"EBM_POWER":1,"EBM_MAX_POWER":106,"COMP_pct_FINAL":0,"TOTAL_POWER_ABSORBED":10,"POWER_OUT_KW":0,"COOLINGCAPACITY":0}' , '$.subcooling,$.B1,$.B2,$.B3,$.B4,$.B5,$.B6,$.B7,$.B8,$.Discharge,$.Suction,$.High_Pressure,$.Low_Pressure,$.Evaporation,$.Condensation,$.MAX_CMP_SPEED,$.Thermal_Limit,$.SH,$.EEV_pct,$.COP,$.DSH,$.WaterFlux,$.FanPower,$.DeltaTtoStart,$.DeltaPtoStart,$.CMP_ROTOR_RPS,$.SET_CH_FLASH,$.SET_HP_FLASH,$.SET_DHW_FLASH,$.Defrosting,$.B8_AVERAGE,$.SET_PLANT,$.SET_CH_BMS,$.SET_HP_BMS,$.SET_DHW_BMS,$.SET_ACTIVE,$.SET_DSH,$.EEV_INJ_pct,$.LPT,$.HPT,$.PLANT_MODE_MANUAL,$.DHW_MODE_MANUAL,$.WATER_FLOW,$.DISCHARGE_TMP,$.INVERTER_TMP,$.ENVELOP_ZONE,$.EEV_A_STEPS,$.EBM_POWER,$.EBM_MAX_POWER,$.COMP_pct_FINAL,$.TOTAL_POWER_ABSORBED,$.POWER_OUT_KW,$.COOLINGCAPACITY,', '123456', '2021-02-24 10:43:00.00' ,@result_id, @result_message);
```

The table mqttpacket is a system versioned table. Here are the table creation queries.

```
CREATE TABLE test_database.MQTTPacket(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    data_type_id INT NOT NULL,
    customer_id INT NOT NULL,
    data_value INT NULL,
    row_start TIMESTAMP(6) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START INVISIBLE,
    row_end TIMESTAMP(6) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END INVISIBLE,
    inserted_time TIMESTAMP(6) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME(row_start,row_end),
    FOREIGN KEY (data_type_id) REFERENCES test_database.DataTypes(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES test_database.templaricustomers(id)
    )WITH SYSTEM VERSIONING;
```

```
CREATE TABLE `datatypes` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `data_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_general_ci',
    `inserted_date` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `description` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_general_ci',
    `device_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `device_id` (`device_id`) USING BTREE,
    CONSTRAINT `datatypes_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`device_id`) REFERENCES `test_database`.`devices` (`id`) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT
)
```

```
CREATE TABLE `templaricustomers` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `customer_serial_number` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_general_ci',
    `customer_name` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_general_ci',
    `inserted_date` TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(6),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE
)
```

So, when I first call the stored procedure, my result_message variable returns "Query performed successfully. Effected rows :  53" however MySql says

*Affected rows: 107  Found rows: 0  Warnings: 0  Duration for 1 query: 0.015 sec.*

In the second call of the SP, it says

*Affected rows: 160  Found rows: 0  Warnings: 0  Duration for 1 query: 0.031 sec.*

Thankful for any help in advance.

Comment: Create sample fiddle (for example, on dbfiddle.uk, with correct DBMS version) with some sample data, SP call and obtained result. Explain in details the logic of your SP. Show desired result for sample data, explain why obtained result is wrong.

Comment: I don't think you're incrementing variable i inside your loop.

Comment: Hi @NevilleKuyt . I actually changed the logic there to get always 1st Item. So, that's why I am not incrementing the variable i

Comment: That might be even more reason to do as @akina asks...this is very hard to parse as it is, and cunning little "I only ever want the first item" refinements make it even harder!